# How to export from Excel to PDF to a determined location?

Tags: excel, export-to-pdf, vba

I have this code to export to `PDF`, but it goes to the *documents folder*. I'd like to export it to a different location. How do I do that?

**This is the code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("a1:k44").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ru & "REMITO " & Range("C7") & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Include a path in filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export excel as PDF to a specific path, you can use the code below. You will need to adjust it to your needs, this is the base.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="path_here+filename.pdf"

End sub
```

Example:

```
Filename:="C:\Documents\newfolder2\archive.pdf"
```